# Use JQuery dialog box to submit form and display success, failure message

Tags: php, jquery, forms, submit

I am trying to use a jquery dialog box as a sign up form on a project I am working on, basically I am envisioning the dialog box functioning similar to an Iframe.  I want the user to be able to enter their information into the form, the information in the form captured by the next page and entered into our database, then change the content of the dialog box to let the user know they were successfully entered into the database or something went wrong and they need to try again.

Is this possible and if so can anyone point me in the direction of an online tutorial?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm 90% sure he is using the jQueryUI plugin found http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is incredibly broad, but here is how I'd handle such a situation.

First, some setup.  Pages and their purpose

Form Page - Get information from a user
Data Page - Validation,disinfect user input.  On successful validation and db insert, alert "Success"  on failure of either alert "Failure"

On your form page you don't need to do anything special.

On your Data page make 2 flags

```
$data_validates = false;
$data_stores = false;
```

Set them to true when they succeed

Then add

```
if($data_validates && $data_stores)
{
    echo "<script>alert('success');</script>";
}
else
{
    echo "<script>alert('success');</script>";
}
```

We are just printing out the javascript to do the alert box.  You could replace that with any legal javascript.  Since PHP gets done server side, all the javascript you generate with it will be there for the browser to intepret AFTER it gets your page.

Update:  Some advice:

If you want to use javascript to popup an alert box, accept input, check a database for that things existance, and then reply with a yes or no, you are going to need to employ a lot of tools.  To do that I would create a RESTful API (using slim and redbeanphp is my favorite) and then use ajax to send a request for a json response.

If you want to use php to modify the value of an alert box/dictate WHEN to alert: my example is a good starting place.

jQuery is not javascript.  Javascript is the language that powers all the awesome cool things that jQuery can do... which is not to say that jQuery doesn't have a language of its own (like the multiple uses of language?)

Comment: Thanks for the input Jake, I apologize I know the question was broad and poorly phrased.  I think my real question is, can I use JQuery dialog box to do everything described above?  When I try to submit the form with a regular submit button the user is directed away from the page and the dialog box closes, I would like to do this without the dialog box ever closing.

Comment: I'm not sure what a jquery dialog box is.  Do you mean http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/ ?

Comment: Okay, I think what you want to do is to use .getJSON or .ajax to send a request to another page (behind the scenes), and call a success handler on that ajax reponse.  with .getJSON you use .success (similar: .error, .complete).  WIth .ajax the syntax is a bit different.

I hope that helps.  From that you should be able to change the title of your question to get more help, or search SO with a new vocabulary

Comment: Thanks for the help Jake I really appreciate it, you are correct I need to use ajax to submit the information and do the work then return a success handler.  I had tried using AJAX before but not with a success handler I think that will be the key.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, "submitting a form via javascript" is a common albeit recently frowned upon process ( see: Privacy news articles of late )

http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-form-submit.phtml

The link above will walk you through the process, it is up to you to determine if what you are doing requires this procedure and then you'll need to determine "is this the best approach"

good luck.

edit: This should be a javascript NOT a php question.